# Is there a way for python to create a variable from a videos soundtrack

Tags: python, applescript

I am working on a program that should press <kbd>cmd+b</kbd> every time a whistle blows in a sports game.
The whistle has a much higher amplitude than the rest of the sounds, so it's visually easy to spot the whistles and I would like the program to do the same.

Comment: What are you asking ?  I don't see a question here.

Comment: Are you trying to do something in a videoeditor based on that "whistle"?

Comment: Something like this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648151/python-frequency-detection